# Black screen after windows10 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, live-usb, windows-10

I have asus laptop with two os: windows10 and ubuntu 16.04

I updated windows10 yesterday. Then my laptop stopped working. Grub2 menu doesnt appear so I could not fix it using a liveUSB

*details*

here is exactly what happened lately because I am not sure which one causes it:

1. my windows10 partition was 60 gb. windows asked for more space so I moved my ubuntu partition a bit to have an unallocated space between windows and ubuntu. then extended windows.

I dont think this broke anything, because I opened ubuntu afterward and it was working just fine. windows too.

2. I updated windows. And things fot weird here. The default os is ubuntu so when restarting grub2 select ubuntu. while updating windows, it showed me a message saying it will restart the computer multiple times. the first time it restarted I was not near it so ubuntu ran by default. for some reason ubuntu couldbt take keyboard input, and the wifi option dissapeared (the only thing available was "networking"). I figured it has something to so with windows so i rebooted to windows and it continued the updates. It rebooted again and i was near it so I made sure to choose windows. Right after that it broke and showed black screen.

I pressed the power button and it shut down. but right after that no matter how many times I press the power button I hear the fan, and it shows me that it is running but the screen is pitch black

How to fix this?

EDIT: laptop was overheating all of the sudden even though it was closed and not plugged to charger. It probably is a hardware problem at this point. I will see if I can bring it to a technician

Comment: Can you get into bios? also idk if this is the best place for this

Comment: nope i couldnt get into BIOS.Honestly I usually access it by grub2 so I tried pressing F2 and power button and nothing worked :(. where should I ask?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue. You could be looking at a blown PSU, but you need a multimeter to check it. Also bad memory module or blown mobo would cause the same symptoms. But first I'd disconnect the HDD and any graphics card and try to boot into BIOS. If you can, then I'd suspect your HDD is faulty.

Comment: it probably is a hardware problem. Since it stopped working completely now after overheating